# Configuration.GetSection("SectionName") is always null when using manually added settings.json file to dotnet core console app

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to add settings.json file manually to a .net core 2.1 console application. So I add these NuGet packages to the project:

> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

and create the `appsettings.json` file like this:

```
{
  "Section1": {
    "Prop1": "value",
    "Prop2": 300
  }
}
```

Finally, I try to get value from the settings file like this:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

_configuration = builder.Build();
var section = _configuration.GetSection("Section1");//section.Value is null
var test = _configuration.GetSection("Section1:Prop1");//it returns the proper value
var model = section as Section1Model;
```

But, `section.Value` is `null` and in consequence, the `model` is `null`. If I try to get values like `_configuration.GetSection("Section1:Prop1")` it returns the correct value. Also, If I call `_configuration.GetSection("Section1).GetChildren()` it returns a collection of settings. What I did wrong?

P.S: I promise the settings file is copied to the bin folder

Comment: More than likely it's because the json file is not in the directory with your binaries.

Comment: Yes, it is. otherwise, how `_configuration.GetSection("Section1:Prop1")` works properly?

Comment: What happens if optional:false is set? I would imagine your not copying the appsettings.json file to the bin directory so it's never actually reading your file.

Comment: @asawyer Nothing, just the same as before. I promise the settings file is copied to the bin directory!

Comment: `ConfigurationBuilder` isn't going to magically cough up `Section1Model` objects. You'll get a generic `IConfigurationSection` interface, with the properties accessible through the indexer or through `GetChildren`, but without a `Value`, as that applies only to scalars. To bind this to a plain old object, use `ConfigurationBinder.Get()` or `ConfgurationBinder.Bind()`. (Normally, this is done under the covers by calling appropriate extension methods on a `ServiceCollection`, like `.AddOptions`, but you can do things manually if you want.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Aah, thank you, it works. Please add it as a solution to make me able to mark it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConfigurationBuilder` only returns generic `IConfiguration` instances. If you want a strongly typed model out of that, it has to be bound first. There are several ways of doing that -- Microsoft's own implementation lives in `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder`. This then gives you access to the static class `ConfigurationBinder` in several ways with extension methods on `IConfiguration`:

```
var model = _configuration.GetSection("Section1").Get<Section1Model>();
```

Oddly enough there's no extension method for directly getting a section into an object, but it would be easy enough to write one.

If you're using dependency injection (`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions`) there'll be a `.Configure<Section1Model>()` extension method to register this binding.